# Edit .razor files in blazor-hosted at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

Basically you can edit the html and everything else in a View with a normal ASP.Net Core MVC application at Runtime. Is this also possible with an blazor hosted app and a .razor file, at least in Development?

#### Update

For anyone else wondering like me, there is currently an open issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5456) regarding to this.

Comment: Why don't you attempt to do it yourself ?

Comment: Well I did try and it does not work, that is the question. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something like hot reload during development it might one day be supported but obviously not yet. As for deployed code that is unlikely but who knows what the future brings